# Declare once vs. repeat declaration

Tags: java, bytecode

Imagine a function in those versions:

```java
    static int fibonacciIterative(int n) {
        int previous = 0;
        int current = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = current;
            current += previous;
            previous = temp;
        }
        return current;
    }
```

```java
    static int fibonacciIterative(int n) {
        int previous = 0;
        int current = 1;
        int temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            temp = current;
            current += previous;
            previous = temp;
        }
        return current;
    }
```

The only difference is that the variable `temp` is declared *again and again* in the loop of the first version, while it's declared *once* outside the loop in the second version. Is there any difference in the resulting bytecode regardless the significance? How is the compiler handling such cases and can the second version be regarded as an *optimized* first version?

Comment: _the variable temp is declared again and again in the loop_ It's not. The java compiler will change that. You can verify by decompiling the compiled class and comparing the source code generated by the decompiler with your original source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables aren't declared at all at the bytecode level (ignoring the usual caveats about debug metadata). Instead, each method has a table of up to 65,535 "slots" that the bytecode can store and retrieve values from. The compiler will assign each variable a slot, making sure not to reuse slots for variables with overlapping liveness ranges.

So in your example, I would expect the only difference to be that `temp` and `i` get assigned slots in a different order, but the bytecode is otherwise identical.

That being said, this is even more irrelevant than you might think, because bytecode is not what is executed (most of the time) by the JVM. Instead, it is merely an abstraction. For any code where performance actually matters, the JVM will do static analysis on your code and then optimize it and compile it to native code, so trivial differences in bytecode encoding are completely meaningless anyway.